# Is there a preinstalled zoom / product magnify feature in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, zoom

I've read that it should have installed with it already working. It's not. Any suggestions how to get this going?

V 2.0.13 Luma child theme

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `magnifier` `var` and its child `var` into `view.xml` file of your theme's etc folder.

```
<var name="magnifier">
            <var name="fullscreenzoom">5</var>  <!-- Zoom for fullscreen (integer)-->
            <var name="top"></var> <!-- Top position of magnifier -->
            <var name="left"></var> <!-- Left position of magnifier -->
            <var name="width"></var> <!-- Width of magnifier block -->
            <var name="height"></var> <!-- Height of magnifier block -->
            <var name="eventType">hover</var> <!-- Action that atcivates zoom (hover/click) -->
            <var name="enabled">true</var> <!-- Turn on/off magnifier (true/false) -->
</var>
```

Comment: My view.xml file has enabled=false in the magnifier but it still is operational on my site. Any other places I need to check? Cache is flushed, reindexed data, static content deployed, etc...

Comment: this will overlap the content on right hand side